# Ruby on Rails ActionListener?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I come from a java programming background. Currently trying to learn RoR by building a little test app. I have a database setup with a dropdown menu populated from the database. How would I get user choice from the dropdown menu?

In java it would be something like a JButton with an actionlistenr attached to it. I have my submit button figured out, but how do I attach it to my dropdown menu such that when the button is pressed it gets the user's current choice? My action/view are listed below. The end idea here is that the user selects something from the dropdown menu, clicks the submit button, and then the submit button calls another action and passes the user's choice along to to the action.

This is my index action in my controller:

```
def index
@ccmh = Ccmh.all
@column_names = Ccmh.columns.map {|a| a.name}
end
```

The action gets the model's database. It also gets the column names of the database in an array format.

This is index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Make Your Selections</h1>
<p>
Y-Axis
</p>
<select name="id">
    <%= @ccmh.each do |abc|%>
    <option value="<% abc.id %>"><%= abc.description %></option>
    <% end %>   
</select>
<p>
X-Axis
</p>


<select name="id">
<% @column_names.each do |a|%>
<option value ="<%@column_names.index%>"><%= a %></option>
<% end %>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<button name ="button" type ="submit">Button</button>
```

This creates 2 dropdown menus. One which is populatd with the value of the description column of the databse, the other is the column names themselves. The idea is that the user selects some data from the database, and then the data will be passed to another view class and rendered as a graph. Not 100% sure how I want to handle doing that as of yet, but I figured some context may help.

Comment: You'll want to catch up on the [Rails Screencasts](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts/).

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be in a form element. The form will determine which action the button will issue a post or get to, along with other things like the verb (post, get etc.)

Rails has helpers for these. If you post your controller and view code we can offer advice on how to make it efficient and workable.

Also try generating a scaffold. This should give you an idea how to wire up forms, buttons and inputs.

In the command-line:

```
rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

would generate a model and database migration for a posts database table. It will also generate controller methods and views to allow you to edit and create them.

```
rake db:migrate
```

will create the table in your database. you can now restart your sever and play with the new pages. Try navigating to /posts and looking at the new files in the controllers and views directories.

Comment: Added my action/views. I don't actually need to create new database entries, I just need to access specified database records and then pass them to another view.

Comment: The idea is to see code generated by Rails to see how you might go about doing it yourself. What you want in the view though is a form:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html Your model and controller together make a resource. By using form_for you can pass in the model and rails works out the route for it. The form we default to post, I believe, which will call the create action. You render the form in the view for the add action. For updates, use the edit action for form rendering and update action for updating the model. Pass method: put into the form.